# Bootstrap grid - center-block doesnt position elements in the center - why?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question. I have a bootstrap (3) grid with 2 columns. insight the right column I am using 'center-block' to position elements in the center. For some reason it doesnt do nothing. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

https://jsfiddle.net/codingcodingcoding/mbw45xdh/1/

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="googleMap"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="center-block">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone phone-icon"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope email-icon"></span>
                    <p>
                        <a href="mailto:your-email@your-domain.com">feedback@example.com</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your `text-center` class in div element

like:

```
<section id="contact">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="text-center">
          <h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="googleMap"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="center-block">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone phone-icon"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope email-icon">
                </span>
                <p>
                    <a href="mailto:your-email@your-
                    domain.com">feedback@example.com</a>
                </p>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: your solution also does not make the elements (my icons etc) be centered -i tried it out- and usually center-block is for divs to place all elements insight it in the center

Comment: sorry i just copy pasted your solution and it didnt have text-center so it didnt work, but yes when i add text-center instead of center-block, it works. can you tell me why? Usually center-block is for diffs and text-center for other elements